# HTML/CSS parent element full width of grandparent (unknown parent height)

Tags: html, css, parent

I have little problem with my blocks. Now i have markup like on screenshot. I need to make child element (yellow background) full with of grandparent (red border). I tried to use posistion: absolute to child element and sure position relative to grandparent and parent. But it's goes wrong because as we all know absolute position 'removed from flow'. So i don't have any idea how to find solution with this trouble.

Also height of grandparent, parent and child don't have fixed value.

[image: my markup now]

My code now:

```css
body.home #content {
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

body.home #content::before,
body.home #content::after {
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1
}

body.home #content::after {
    clear: both
}

body.home #content .cat-list {
    padding-right: .625rem;
    padding-left: .625rem;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}

@media print,
screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    body.home #content .cat-list {
        padding-right: .9375rem;
        padding-left: .9375rem
    }
}

body.home #content .cat-list,
body.home #content .cat-list:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    float: left;
    clear: none
}

body.home #content .cat-list:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    float: right
}

body.home #content .cat-list>.item {
    float: left;
    width: 20%
}

body.home #content .cat-list>.item:nth-of-type(1n) {
    clear: none
}

body.home #content .cat-list>.item:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
    clear: both
}

body.home #content .cat-list>.item:last-child {
    float: left
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item {
    margin-bottom: .9375rem
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item a.cat-link {
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item a.cat-link img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item a.cat-link:focus+.subcats-list {
    display: block
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item .subcats-list {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0
}

body.home #content .cat-list .item .subcats-list a {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.7.4/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body class="home">
<div id="content" class="grid-x">
  <div class="cat-list">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="cat-link">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, quam.
      </a>
      <ul class="subcats-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="cat-link">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, quam.
      </a>
      <ul class="subcats-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="cat-link">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, quam.
      </a>
      <ul class="subcats-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="cat-link">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, quam.
      </a>
      <ul class="subcats-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't completely understand as the code you have given doesn't tally with the verbal description - the child and parent aren't positioned in the CSS. Anyway, if you want the yellow element to have the width of its grandparent you should not give the parent a position. Perhaps you could make your snippet into code we could run.

Comment: Fixed my code, sorry for my mistake. Now it work well. Any idea?